# Проблема с созданием диалогового окна

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5, сигналы-слоты, qdialog

Возникла проблема с созданием дополнительных окон. В окне `ChooseWindow` есть две кнопки,
в зависимости от нажатия кнопки открывается разные окна. 
В одном ввод файла, в другом ввод размеров для изображения.

Нужно чтобы при нажатии на вторую кнопку отображался интерфейс с вводом размеров и при вводе размеров окна сворачивались.

Как это реализовать?

```
Пример кода:

class CreatePicture(QtWidgets.QDialog):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QtWidgets.QWidget.__init__(self, parent)
        self.input_width = QtWidgets.QPushButton("Width")
        self.input_height = QtWidgets.QPushButton("Height")
        self.vbox = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        self.vbox.addWidget(self.input_width)
        self.vbox.addWidget(self.input_height)
        self.setLayout(self.vbox)
        self.input_width.clicked.connect(self.on_width)
        self.input_height.clicked.connect(self.on_height)

    def on_width(self):
        width_length, ok = QInputDialog.getInt(self, 'Width of picture in px', 'Enter width')
        if ok:
            global_variables['width'] = width_length

    def on_height(self):
        height_length, ok = QInputDialog.getInt(self, 'Height of picture in px', 'Enter height')
        if ok:
            global_variables['height'] = height_length

class ChooseWindow(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QtWidgets.QWidget.__init__(self, parent)
        self.choosepicture = QtWidgets.QPushButton("Выбрать фото")
        self.createproject = QtWidgets.QPushButton("Создать проект")
        self.vbox = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        self.vbox.addWidget(self.choosepicture)
        self.vbox.addWidget(self.createproject)
        self.setLayout(self.vbox)
        self.createproject.clicked.connect(self.on_create_project)
        self.choosepicture.clicked.connect(self.on_open_file)

    def on_create_project(self):
        testGui = CreatePicture()
        testGui.resize(500, 500)
        testGui.show()

    def on_open_file(self):
        workspace = QtWidgets.QFileDialog.getOpenFileUrl(parent=self, caption="Выберите файл",
                                                         directory=QtCore.QDir.currentPath(),
                                                         filter="Image Files (*.png *.jpg *.bmp ")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    dialogWindow = ChooseWindow()
    dialogWindow.setWindowTitle('Select')
    dialogWindow.resize(200, 150)
    dialogWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: чтобы CreatePicture появился рядом при клике на `on_open_file`? это невозможно, т.к. вы вызываете в `on_open_file` диалог, а он появляется модальным

Comment: @gil9red мне нужно окно createPicture , при нажатии кнопки createproject,а не open_file

Comment: судя по коду, у вас и вызовится `on_create_project` при клике на кнопку createproject

Comment: @gil9red "нужно чтобы при нажатии на вторую кнопку отображался интерфейс с вводом размеров." вторая кнопка "createProject",а интерфейс create picture, который должен появляться после нажатия кнопки , но он не отображается вот в чем трабл

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте это:

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtGui     
from PyQt5 import QtCore    
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets 

class CreatePicture(QtWidgets.QDialog):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QtWidgets.QWidget.__init__(self, parent)
        self.parent = parent

        self.input_width  = QtWidgets.QPushButton("Width")
        self.input_height = QtWidgets.QPushButton("Height")
        self.vbox = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        self.vbox.addWidget(self.input_width)
        self.vbox.addWidget(self.input_height)
        self.setLayout(self.vbox)
        self.input_width.clicked.connect(self.on_width)
        self.input_height.clicked.connect(self.on_height)

        self.global_variables = {} # ++

    def on_width(self):
        width_length, ok = QtWidgets.QInputDialog.getInt(self, 'Width of picture in px', 'Enter width')
        if ok:
            self.global_variables['width'] = width_length

    def on_height(self):
        height_length, ok = QtWidgets.QInputDialog.getInt(self, 'Height of picture in px', 'Enter height')
        if ok:
            self.global_variables['height'] = height_length
        try:   # ++     
            if self.global_variables['width'] and self.global_variables['height']:
                self.hide() 
                self.parent.on_project(self.global_variables['width'], self.global_variables['height'])
        except:
            QtWidgets.QMessageBox.information(None, "Error", "Введите все параметры проекта! "
                                              "'width' и 'height'",
                                              QtWidgets.QMessageBox.Ok)


class ChooseWindow(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QtWidgets.QWidget.__init__(self, parent)
        self.choosepicture = QtWidgets.QPushButton("Выбрать фото")
        self.createproject = QtWidgets.QPushButton("Создать проект")
        self.vbox = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        self.vbox.addWidget(self.choosepicture)
        self.vbox.addWidget(self.createproject)
        self.setLayout(self.vbox)
        self.createproject.clicked.connect(self.on_create_project)
        self.choosepicture.clicked.connect(self.on_open_file)

        self.workspace = None           # ++
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel() # ++
        self.vbox.addWidget(self.label) # ++

    def on_create_project(self):
        self.testGui = CreatePicture(self)
        self.testGui.resize(500, 500)
        self.testGui.show()

    def on_open_file(self):
        self.workspace, ok = QtWidgets.QFileDialog.getOpenFileUrl(parent=self, caption="Выберите файл",
                                                         directory=QtCore.QDir.currentPath(),
                                                         filter="Image Files (*.png *.jpg *.bmp) ") # ++
    # ++
    def  on_project (self, w, h):
        pathImg = self.workspace.path()[1:]
        pix   = QtGui.QPixmap(pathImg)              
        pix1  = pix.scaled(int(w), int(h))
        self.label.setPixmap(pix1)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    dialogWindow = ChooseWindow()
    dialogWindow.setWindowTitle('Select')
    dialogWindow.resize(200, 150)
    dialogWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]